# Create a list from file in python

Tags: python, string, file, list

I have a .txt file like this:

```
John 26
Mary 48
Nick 34
```

I want import them and put them in a list so that I can find specific elements. For example age[1] would have the value 48, name[1] the value Mary etc.

I tried doing

```
import sys,random
f = open('example.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
        tokens=line.split()
        a=tokens[0]
        print a[1]
```

but the result of print a[1] is the second letter of each string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `a[1]`, you want `tokens[1]`.

This is the value of `a`, which is the first element of `tokens`:

```
Nick
```

But the second element of `tokens` is the age:

```
"34"
```

As @user mentioned, you probably wanted to have it as integer, not a string. You can convert it to integer:

```
a = int(tokens[1])
```

@thefourtheye proposed a nice solution. I think i'll propose to store it in a dictionary:

```
with open('example.txt') as f:
    ages = {}
    for line in f:
        d = line.split()
        ages[d[0]] = int(d[1])
```

And here is `ages`:

```
{'John':26, 'Mary':48, 'Nick':34}
```

To retrieve the age of `John`:

```
print(ages['John'])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Might as well preempt the next bug while we're at it: `tokens[1]` is a string, so trying to do math with it won't work properly unless you convert it to an `int` first.

Comment: We don't yet know that OP is going to try to do math on the age field. :-)

Comment: Yes but tokens[1] prints the whole column. How can I select the specific value 34? tokens[1][2] returns the 3rd character...

Comment: @qwrrty: Maybe he'll do math on the name field as a base-36 number? :)

Comment: @Galil: `tokens[1]` is not the whole column, it's the age of the current line. Presumably the reason you're _seeing_ a whole column is that you're just trying to `print` all of the names and ages, rather than storing them in any `age` and `name` lists. To do that, just `age.append(a)` instead of `print(a)`. (Or do it thefourtheye's way.)

Comment: @Galil: See [this example](http://pastebin.com/K9ap21Nf) of applying this answer to your code. (You can also add the `int` part if you want, and of course you can simplify it; I just wanted to keep it as simple as possible to make sure you understood why this answer solves your problem.)

Answer (score 2):

1. While reading from a file, always use `with`, so that you dont have to worry about closing the file.
2. Then, you can read lines and split them and finally unzip them like this

   ```
   with open('Input.txt', 'r') as inFile:
       names, ages = zip(*(line.rstrip().split() for line in inFile))
       print names, ages
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   ('John', 'Mary', 'Nick') ('26', '48', '34')
   ```
3. You can access the individual names and ages like this

   ```
   names[0], ages[0]
   ```

Comment: Better with a genexpr than a listcomp. No point building an extra list for no reason. But otherwise, I was writing the exact same thing (I hesitated over the genexpr vs. `map` choice and you beat me to it).